# Can you crop a photo to fit a circle using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, photo, editing

I know that ffmpeg is very advanced and can be used to crop both photos and videos in order to rescale them. Bit mostly everything I've come across online uses the X and Y coordinates to crop a photo in ffmpeg. How can we use this to crop a photo in the form of a circle rather than a rectangle?

Comment: Not quite. Images are always rectangular. However, you can achieve a circular effect by generating a circular mask. See https://superuser.com/questions/1270950/

Answer (score 1):

It takes ava.jpg, rescales it to 400:400 and applies the mask:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner  -i "ava.jpg" -i "mask.png" -filter_complex [0]scale=400:400[ava];[1]alphaextract[alfa];[ava][alfa]alphamerge circle_ava.png
```

mask.png is just a circle, example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I needed the same thing and couldn't get @electron's solution to work. I modified it a bit and it works as expected:

```
ffmpeg -i avatar.png -i mask.png -filter_complex "[0]scale=400:400[ava];[1]alphaextract[alfa];[ava][alfa]alphamerge" output.png
```